# Symmetry subgroup of a cube

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3)$ with $\epsilon_i\in\{\pm 1\}$ and consider for each $\epsilon$:

$$
D_\epsilon=\begin{pmatrix}
    \epsilon_1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \epsilon_2 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \epsilon_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $O_h\subseteq GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ be

$$
O_h =\{P_\sigma D_\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^{(3,3)}\mid \sigma\in S_3, \epsilon\text{ as above}\}
$$

where $P_\sigma$ is the associated permutation matrix with $(P_\sigma)_{ij}=\delta_{i\sigma(j)}$. I want to prove that $O_h$ forms a subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$. I've already had some thoughts about it, the cases for associativity is clear as it would be inherited from $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$, same goes for the identity and its properties. My problem actually lies with proving closure of the set. My guess is that for $A=P_\sigma D_\epsilon,B=P_\tau D_{\epsilon'}$, we have

$$AB=P_\sigma D_\epsilon P_\tau D_{\epsilon'}= P_{\sigma\circ\tau}D_{\epsilon''}$$

where $\epsilon''_i=\epsilon_{\sigma(i)}\epsilon'_i$.

Comment: Check by example what happens if you take $P_\sigma D_\epsilon P_{\sigma^{-1}}$.  Then prove it.  Now you can compute all products.

Comment: Can you provide this more thoroughly?

Comment: Compute some examples, and ask again in 24 hours if you haven't gained any insight.   Note that your set of matrices is the set of "permutation matrices with signed entries".   You can get any such matrix by multiplying a  permutation matrix on the right by a $D_\epsilon$ or on the left by a $D_{\epsilon'}$.  How are the two $D$ matrices related?

Comment: I figured something out and edited my answer, can you have a look on it ?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.